# All of a sudden I get a StackoverflowError using mariadb (mysql) and jdbc, why?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I just rebuild one of my company's applications
(which is working fine in production and there were no changes from the master branch),
and all of a sudden I get a
`java.lang.StackOverflowError`.
My colleague also built the app on his machine and he also gets the same error which is weird since we use separate local `MySQL` databases.

Has a dependency of `mariaDB` changed recently?

Here is the complete Exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLPreparedStatement.&lt;init&gt;(MySQLPreparedStatement.java:89)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLConnection.prepareStatement(MySQLConnection.java:181)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1565)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:621)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:714)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRowFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2803)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2756)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:539)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1173)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:425)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3267)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:326)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2328)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1848)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2178)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1505)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:462)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.refreshObjectIfRequired(ObjectBuilder.java:4305)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:1040)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:737)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:689)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:803)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:548)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1173)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:425)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3267)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:326)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2328)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1848)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2178)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1505)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:462)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.refreshObjectIfRequired(ObjectBuilder.java:4305)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:1040)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:899)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:852)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:735)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:689)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:803)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:944)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:555)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1173)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:442)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1220)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.handler.impl.DatabaseHandlerImpl.getGenericData(DatabaseHandlerImpl.java:118)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.controller.DatabaseFacade.getTimelineDatas(DatabaseFacade.java:93)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.service.validationService.ValidationService.getInvalidTransporters(ValidationService.java:34)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.doTransportaterValidations(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:159)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.doCompleteValidations(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:125)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.doInitialValidations(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:145)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.SingleTimelineImpl.refreshGraphicalTimeline(SingleTimelineImpl.java:312)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.SingleTimelineImpl.&lt;init&gt;(SingleTimelineImpl.java:58)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.model.TimelineData.getGraphicalTimeline(TimelineData.java:659)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.model.TimelineData.resetStartAndEndTimes(TimelineData.java:421)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.recalcEndDateIfOverlappingInterval(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:242)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.doDateValidations(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:222)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.doCompleteValidations(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:126)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.doInitialValidations(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:145)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.SingleTimelineImpl.refreshGraphicalTimeline(SingleTimelineImpl.java:312)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.SingleTimelineImpl.&lt;init&gt;(SingleTimelineImpl.java:58)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.model.TimelineData.getGraphicalTimeline(TimelineData.java:659)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.model.TimelineData.resetStartAndEndTimes(TimelineData.java:421)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.recalcEndDateIfOverlappingInterval(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:242)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.doDateValidations(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:222)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.doCompleteValidations(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:126)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.presenter.SingleTimelinePresenter.doInitialValidations(SingleTimelinePresenter.java:145)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.SingleTimelineImpl.refreshGraphicalTimeline(SingleTimelineImpl.java:312)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.SingleTimelineImpl.&lt;init&gt;(SingleTimelineImpl.java:58)
at MYCOMPANY.liferay.model.Timel…
```

Comment: I think the culprit is not `MySQL`/`MariaDB`, but the middleware `EclipseLink`...

Comment: never ending loop suspect around `refreshgraphicalTimeline`...`recalcEndDateIfOverlappingInterval`...`getGraphicalTimeline` (see start of stack trace)

Comment: @Usagi Can you specify?

Comment: @Carlos Thanks, but those are different timelines that are worked upon

Answer (score 1):

If there were really no differences in the code,
then there is a difference between in the data in your local db instance and the data in the production db instance.

You have an infinite (or just a super deep loop) in either `MYCOMPANY.liferay.view.singleTimeline.SingleTimelineImpl` or what ever is using it.

Consider including the entire exception dump when you ask for people to "please look at my exception dump to help me"